# add className when find item in other array of items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So I have a list of initial selected items which I receive from the parent component. something like this

```
props.initialSelectedItems = [{id:1, name: 'itemABC'}, {id: 10, name: 'helloWorld'}]
```

In this same component I have the an array with all the available items:

```
itemsArr = [{id:1, name: 'itemABC'}, {id: 2, name: 'item123'}.... {id:100, name:'OneMoreItem'}]
```

So I want to render this list and when theres a match with the item on `props.initialSelectedItems` I want to add a className to that item. So I have the following code

```
    const checkInitialState = (itemId: number): boolean => {
        for (let i = 0; i<props.initialSelectedItems.length; i++) {
            const initial = props.initialSelectedItems[i];
            return initial.id === itemId;    
        }
    }

const createItemRows = (itemsArr: Item[]): any => {
        let resultsRow= [];

        for(let i=0; i<itemsArr.length; i++){
            const item: Item = itemsArr[i];
            const isInitialSelected: boolean = checkInitialState(item.id);
            resultsRow.push(
                <div key={i}
                    className={`list__row ${isInitialSelected && 'initial-selected'}`}
                >
.....
```

So my problem is that it only return true for one of the matched items.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `checkInitialState` ALWAYS returns on the first iteration

Comment: There is a simpler way to do this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript

Comment: @TedBrownlow Thanks. So stupid of me.  :(  It's solved.